# File transfer using Sockets

Tags: c#, wpf, sockets, file-transfer

I need to transfer all type of files to a particular user based on his IPaddress and particular port.So whenever a new request comes at the specified port(the port where the servere is waiting for file) it means that a file is transferred,if its in another port some chat message is transferred.

My problem is i need to have the sent file name and size as well along with its content so that at the client side a new downloaded file will be created(with the same name) as the sent file.How can i go about this.Also i need to know the size of the file,so that i can create a byte array to receive the content.And my code is here.Please help me out

```
   public void fileClient()
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 40399);
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.ShowDialog();
            string fileName = dlg.FileName;
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
            string fileNameandSize = fi.Name + "." + fi.Length;
            byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
                       Stream stream = client.GetStream();
              stream.SetLength(fi.Length);//If i set the file length here am getting an exception
                       stream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length); 
            client.Close();
        }

public void fileServer()
    {
        TcpListener list;
        Int32 port1 = 40399;
        list = new TcpListener(port1);
        list.Start();
        TcpClient client = list.AcceptTcpClient();
        MessageBox.Show("Client trying to connect");
        Thread.Sleep(10);
            Stream stream = client.GetStream();
        byte[] receivedBytes = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(receivedBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt16(stream.Length));  
                   string fileName = "C:\\Users\\dhivya.s\\Desktop\\Recent received";
                    File.WriteAllBytes(fileName + "\\" + "newFile", receivedBytes);
        list.Stop();
        client.Close();
    }
```

Comment: You need to define a communication _protocol_ for your application. This can be in-band or out-of-band.

Comment: I cant understand your comment

Comment: How the two communicate together in order to tell each other what is going on. While the socket is wrapped neatly into a class, you need to define the language in which the two sides talk. To them, they are just getting byte data. You need some way of saying "hey I am sending you a file" so that the other side knows what to expect

Comment: Thats what i meant by port selection.Since its my chat application whenever a file upload is selected it will be sent at a particular port only.In the other side also files will be sent at a particular port only so it will be automatically done rite.

Comment: Unless you have a really good reason to write your own protocol, try using one that already exists (i.e. HTTP, FTP, XMPP etc.)

Comment: Actually am using this in an intranet chat application.Will it be a good step if i use HTTP and FTP ?

Comment: In your case, since it's a chat application, you'd probably want to look at the XMPP protocol: http://xmpp.org/xmpp-protocols/

Comment: can you pls suggest me some XMPP examples so that i can understand it better(Like codeproject sites)

Comment: @Miky Dinescu Can you pls help me

Comment: @Newto.net I've tried to help you by pointing you in the right direction. You'll have to be a little more specific about what exactly is not working. Are you just trying to learn by writing your own chat application or is there a specific business requirement? If it's the former, start with something small and build upon that (ask some specific questions along the way). If it's a business requirement you have to be specific about why you can't use the XMPP or other already existing protocol. As it stands your question is way to broad!

Answer (score 2):

File transfers like this rely on there being an agreed protocol between the end ends. For example you could define a simple protocol whereby the first four bytes specify the size of the file name, the next four the size of the file. Then send the file name, then the content. Then all you have to worry about is whether both ends of the wire use either big or little endian. If they are the same, you're fine.

This is why sockets aren't often a good choice for communications. There are plenty of existing protocols for transferring files (HTTP, FTP, AMF etc), which already handle this stuff for you. So why not use one of them?

Comment: Any sites you know to refer for similar examples ?

Comment: Nto to forget, when you want to implement security, protocols like HTTP and FTP have native support on this

Answer (score 2):

Without any checking, this seems to work. You can add checksums etc., decode the b64 save the file.

```
public class FileTransfer
{
    public string Name;
    public int Size;
    public string Content;
}
```

Send:

```
FileTransfer fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
fileTransfer.Name = "TestFile";
fileTransfer.Content = System.Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes("c:\\data\\test.html"));
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(fileTransfer.GetType());
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 40399);
Stream stream = client.GetStream();
x.Serialize(stream, fileTransfer);
client.Close();
```

Rec:

```
TcpListener list;
Int32 port1 = 40399;
list = new TcpListener(port1);
list.Start();
TcpClient client = list.AcceptTcpClient();
Console.WriteLine("Client trying to connect");
Stream stream = client.GetStream();
XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FileTransfer));
FileTransfer myObject = (FileTransfer)mySerializer.Deserialize(stream);
Console.WriteLine("name: " + myObject.Name);
list.Stop();
client.Close();
```